# How to automatically download many images

Tags: images, download, automation

I need to download all pictures from this site: http://bobrowo.org.pl/galeriav.php 
I tried to do something with HTTrack but didn't work very well.
It would be awesome to save dates and descriptions also somehow, to a text file or something.
Using the source of the site, I've got all options from the switch
`<option value=40 > -Rajd rowerowy
<option value=41 > -Wieczornica nt. Księży "Tych, którzy odeszli"
<option value=42 > -Szkolenie "Zachowanie dziedzictwa ..."
etc.`
These are gallery id and description.
That's what I've been thinking about:
`+http://bobrowo.org.pl/galeriav.php?idkat=41 -O "C:\Bobrowo\41"
+http://bobrowo.org.pl/galeriav.php?idkat=42 -O "C:\Bobrowo\42"
etc.`
I want to download them to separate folders for every category.
I hope that You understand what I want to do. :)
Thanks in advance for every response.

Comment: well, except the lastest one, all picture has similar url: `http://bobrowo.org.pl/galeria/1h50506<n>.jpg`, n = 1~10. The lastest one is 1h505211.jpg.

Comment: Yes, but they're grouped in categories on the site and I have to keep them grouped like that.

Comment: What operating system and browser?

Comment: Windows 7, Firefox

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox, [FlashGot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashgot/) is a free, popular, and safe extension for downloading all images from a website.

I used it years ago.  Nice to see that it's still actively developed.

Comment: I've just downloaded it, but don't really know how to download all these images with it.

Comment: The problem is, that they're grouped in galleries and I don't know how to download them all at once and with descriptions.

Comment: Yes, the galleries in your example are quite small (less than 10 images).  FlashGot is more useful for large galleries.

Comment: There is a switch on the site which chooses the gallery. I need to download all images from all the galleries and keep them sorted in these galleries.

Answer (score 0):

[Jdownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) is my personal preference, but there are many apps that will follow and download all links to a depth you select.

Comment: There are many apps that do this, but I don't know how to exactly do it, with keeping the information from the website.

Comment: check this out http://serverfault.com/questions/150358/copy-a-website-and-preserve-the-file-folder-structure